# Change Wordpress prefix for only one table?

Tags: database, users, table

I have a little question about Wordpress database.

I want to know: Can I change the wordpress pefix for only one table?
Thet means I use on one Wordpress Page two Prefixes.

If it works how I want to work and anyone know how it works, please write what I can make that it works.

Why I need it?
I have 2 Websites, on the first website can log in all users and on the second website can only log in a little part of this users. But the username and Password have to be the same.

Sorry for my bad English and thanks for the help! ;)

Comment: Are these 2 websites both WordPress? If so, have you consider using multisite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `wp-config.php` for your second site, define the following two constants:

```
define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'yourfirstprefix_users');
define('CUSTOM_USERMETA_TABLE', 'yourfirstprefix_usermeta');
```

You'll have to add some custom logic to your second site limiting logins by user role.

Comment: Did you also know can I use this tabel in an other database?
Thet means all users are in one database alone. (In this database are only the "user table" and the "usermeta table")